# Kendo Grid with JSON and PHP5

Tags: php, javascript, json, html, kendo-ui

Does anybody knows if there is any perfect example available where JSON is implemented in Kendo Grid along with PHP5?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-01-18/get_rolling_with_kendo_ui_and_php_ndash_part_1.aspx) from the Kendo UI team should help.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here is a good one: 
http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/PHP/build-apps-with-kendo-ui-and-php